Why does the focus actually exist in lenses?
Is there a mathematical reason why the rays parallel to the principle axis have to converge or seem to converge at a point when it passes through a lens? The existence of the focus is always assumed everywhere I see. I don't get it, can someone prove to me why the focus exists? Also what I mean by focus is the point where all rays of light parallel to the principle axis meet after passing through a lens.

A parallel ray to the optical axis is plane wave with direction parallel to the optical axis. This plane wave is incident on a lens, with a given curvature, and will be transformed in a spherical wave (for a circular lens). Thus, the wavefronts are spherical and converge towards the focal point. Note that this is only true in the paraxial approximations, without aberrations. https://microscopyu.com/tutorials/perfectlens

@MauvaiseFoi Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

For the maths, you can refer to Fourier Optics by Goodman section 5.1

There doesn't have to be a focus.  In fact, rays passing through an curved refracting surface generally don't create focal points;  witness the patterns of light you see at the the bottom of a pool, where the ripples concentrate light in some spots and divert it away from others, but generally don't create the isolated bright spots we see from a lens.
But for a lens, we specifically design the shape of the curved surface so that the rays all meet in one spot.  In other words, there's a focal point because we specially shaped the piece of glass so that there was a focal point.
Technically, many real-world lenses don't actually make all of the rays converge precisely at a single point.  It turns out to be rather complicated to shape a lens so that this happens, and for many applications this level of precision isn't necessary.  So, many real-world lenses have some degree of aberration, where rays of different colors or rays that are farther from the optical axis are not precisely directed to the focal point.  In particular, it's particularly easy to create lenses whose surfaces are spheres, which leads to spherical aberration and causes a certain level of fuzziness in the images created.  If you want to spend more money to get rid of this fuzziness, you use pricier aspheric lenses instead.

hm ok. So you are saying in any lens which has a focal point, it has a focal point because it was designed so. Then one follow up question. A convex /concave lens has a focal point because it was designed to have one but why that specific shape? Why does a segment of a sphere when turned into a lens have that property of having a focal point? A mathematical reason would be nice.
